# contacts not recognized when body is changed from circle to rectangle

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

With help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32352886/how-to-set-physics-properties-for-a-circle-so-it-follows-given-path) I have made a circle body traverse a given path. I have some bodies at some of the path points and have logged contact in `didBeginContact`. When the body gets in contact with a specific body the circle body is changed to a rectangle. This rectangular body is suppose to traverse the same path as the original circle body but it doesn't reach the path points as the contact is not logged. I tried changing `radiusPoint` to the width or height of the rectangle also but that didn't work. Also the rectangle body is bigger than the circle body. How can I get the rectangle to traverse the points with the contact recognised?  Please see code below.

Code related to path traversal:

```
    let repeats: Bool = true //Whether to repeat the path.
    var pathIndex = 0 //The index of the current point to travel.
    var pointRadius: CGFloat = SKTexture(imageNamed: "circle").size().width //How close the node must be to reach the destination point.
    let travelSpeed: CGFloat = 250 //Speed the node will travel at.
    let rate: CGFloat = 0.9 //Motion smoothing. 0.5

    circlePath = [
    CGPoint(x:screenSize.width , y: screenSize.height/3),
    CGPoint(x: screenSize.width/2, y: platform.sprite.frame.height),
    CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: screenSize.height/3),
    CGPoint(x: CGFloat(pos1) + screenSize.width/20, y: upperSpearPosHeight)]

    final func didReachPoint() {
    //reached point!
    pathIndex++

    if pathIndex >= ballPath.count && repeats {
    pathIndex = 0
    }
    }

    func updatePath() {

    if pathIndex >= 0 && pathIndex < circlePath.count {
    let destination = circlePath[pathIndex]
    //currentPosition = destination
    let displacement = CGVector(dx: destination.x-circle!.sprite.position.x, dy: destination.y-circle!.sprite.position.y)
    let radius = sqrt(displacement.dx*displacement.dx+displacement.dy*displacement.dy)
    let normal = CGVector(dx: displacement.dx/radius, dy: displacement.dy/radius)
    let impulse = CGVector(dx: normal.dx*travelSpeed, dy: normal.dy*travelSpeed)
    let relativeVelocity = CGVector(dx:impulse.dx-circle!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx, dy:impulse.dy-circle!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dy);
    circle!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity=CGVectorMake(circle!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dx+relativeVelocity.dx*rate, circle!.sprite.physicsBody!.velocity.dy+relativeVelocity.dy*rate);

    if radius < pointRadius {
        didReachPoint()
        }
        }
    }
```

Contact code:

```
        func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody : SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask  {
    firstBody = contact.bodyA
    secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
    else    {
    firstBody = contact.bodyB
    secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

            if firstBody.categoryBitMask == circleCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == bonusCategory  {
    let img = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rectangular")
   (firstBody.node! as? SKSpriteNode)?.size = img.size()       
   firstBody.node!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: img, size: img.size())
   firstBody.node!.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false 
   changeCircleAction = SKAction.setTexture(img)   
   firstBody.node!.runAction(changeCircleAction)
 }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == circleCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == platformCategory  {

    print("touched platform")
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == circleCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == smallStarCategory  {

    removeStar(secondBody.node!)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like when you change the `firstBody` to a rectangle (in the `didBeginContact` method), you don't set the bit mask.  From what you described, it appears you want to set it to `circleCategory` as such:

```
firstBody.node!.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = circleCategory
```

I would put this right below the `firstBody.node!.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false`.